# Implications of disabling X-XSS-Protection in Safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, safari, xss

I have an edit action on a rails site which sometimes sends `<iframe>` tags in the params. When this is done on Safari it redirects to a blank page with `data;` as a url. This is done to prevent reflective XSS attacks.

After doing some research online I've found that I can disable this by adding `response.headers['X-XSS-Protection'] = "0"` to the show path it redirects to.

My questions are; how exposed will this now leave the site? And is there a more efficient way of solving this problem?

Comment: "sends <iframe> tags in the params" - is this some sort of CMS where you let users edit the contents?

Comment: Yes exactly, although this is mainly used by the site admin